# Custom prompt function is making form window too small

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a custom dialog box builder that takes a list of controls puts them in a dialog box. The controls can then be accessed later. I'm having an issue that I have the variable `currentSpace` and `largestWidth` and they work until I need them to define the width and height of the form. If I drag the corner to resize the form all the controls are in their proper spots but the window is 1-2 controls too short or too skinny. Any info or help is appreciated all the same

```
public static int ShowDialog(string caption, List<Control> controls)
{
    Form prompt = new Form();
    Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", TabIndex = 1 };
    int currentSpace = 3;
    int largestWidth = 0;
    controls.Add(confirmation);
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        control.Top = currentSpace;
        control.Left = 3;
        if (control.Width > largestWidth)
            largestWidth = control.Width;
        currentSpace += control.Height + control.Padding.Bottom;
        prompt.Controls.Add(control);
    }
    prompt.Width = largestWidth + 6; // not wide enough
    prompt.Height = currentSpace; // not tall enough
    prompt.Text = caption;
    confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
    prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;
    prompt.ShowDialog();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting the `Width` and `Height` separately, set the `ClientSize` which is the inner size of the `Form`. E.g: `prompt.ClientSize = new Size(largestWidth + 6, currentSpace);` that should get you closer.

Comment: @Loathing Thanks for the reply that fixed it perfectly. I have no idea why I was downvoted though because I honestly didn't know the difference and the remarks for `form.size` said that it was different from `DesktopBounds` which looks like the size of the window.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry about the downvotes, that's just how it goes sometimes.